# Android clipboard change listener broke in 4.3?

Tags: android, clipboard

So I have an app that monitors the clipboard and copies the data to a database. Been around since about 4.0 and never had an issue. Now with 4.3 the app you copy from crashes whenever you try to copy. Just something standard like this will do it. Anyone else experience this or know of a workaround?

> ClipboardManager manager = (ClipboardManager)
>   getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
>   manager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new
>   ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
>       @Override
>       public void onPrimaryClipChanged() { } });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark Murphy has a blog post on this subject:

http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/08/08/developer-psa-please-fix-your-clipboard-handling.html

Comment: Well doesn't sound very good. I'm in the latter category. So since my app monitors the clipboard as background service and inputs data into a database I'm sorta screwed until Google fixes it?